# Zoom to nearlest marker to the user location react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

In this case I needs to show at-least one marker and user location on map load. Is there any way to achieve that?

My approach is to get the nearest marker from user location and add it and current user location to `fitToSuppliedMarkers` so it'll show user location and nearest marker and chnage zoom level according to that. any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `animateToRegion()`, as said [here](https://medium.com/@arvind.chak128/how-to-auto-zoom-into-your-current-location-using-react-native-maps-88f9b3063fe7).

Example:

```js
zoomToLocation() {

    let region = {
        latitude: parseFloat(latitudeOfTheMarkerHere),
        longitude: parseFloat(longitudeOfTheMarkerHere),
        latitudeDelta: 5,
        longitudeDelta: 5
    };

    let initialRegion = Object.assign({}, region);
    initialRegion["latitudeDelta"] = 0.005;
    initialRegion["longitudeDelta"] = 0.005;
    this.mapView.animateToRegion(initialRegion, 2000);
  }
```